# Creating a custom JNDI resource

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, jndi, netbeans-8

I want to provide configuration for a web-app I'm developing via the context/JNDI. I'm currently developing in Netbeans 8.1 using the bundled Glassfish server, although my solution should be container-agnostic.

I have working settings for getting database connections, but am stumped with custom resource types.

In web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>SHOWmail/search</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.example.SearchProvider</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In glassfish-resources.xml:

```
    <custom-resource jndi-name="SHOWmail/search" res-type="com.example.SearchProvider" factory-class="com.example.SearchProviderFactory">
    <property name="name" value="value"/>
</custom-resource>
```

In code:

```
   initContext = new InitialContext();
   envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
   search = (SearchProvider)envContext.lookup("SHOWmail/search");
```

I reliable get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:SHOWmail/search`. My factory and class aren't touched (will add if needed).

Pointers on where I've gone wrong greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried `<resource-env-ref>` instead of `<resource-ref>`, with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I misunderstood the different JNDI namespaces here in the netbeans/glassfish combination.

The solution is to look under `java:app` instead of `java:comp/env`; this searches WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml.

web.xml

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>SHOWmail/search</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>com.example.SearchProviderFactory</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<custom-resource jndi-name="java:app/SHOWmail/search" res-type="com.example.ElasticSearchProvider" factory-class="com.example.SearchProviderFactory">
</custom-resource>
```